# C# Insert Into syntax error

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I am trying to insert data into a table in MS Access. I keep getting the error Missing semicolon (;) at end of SQL statement. or a different error saying that i my Insert query needs to have a value or table in it. Here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;



namespace MiddleWare
{
public partial class Sales : Form
{
    public Sales()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int empId = int.Parse(txtEmpID.Text);
        string cmdText = @"INSERT INTO [Sales] 
                        ([Printers], [Ink], [Paper])
               VALUES (@Printers,@Ink,@Paper)
               SELECT @EmpID FROM (Emplopyee)";

        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\cp-stud-nas1\users\mat72462\Documents\SalesData.accdb"))
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, con))
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Printers", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtPrinters.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ink", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtInk.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Paper", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtPaper.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpID", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtEmpID.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpID", txtEmpID.Text);

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [Total Sales] FROM Sales WHERE EmpID=@EmpID";
            string result = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(result);

        }
    }

    private void Sales_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'DataSet1.DataTable1' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.DataTable1TableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet1.DataTable1);






    }

    private void btnReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\cp-stud-nas1\users\mat72462\Documents\SalesData.accdb");

        {
            this.DataTable1TableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet1.DataTable1);

            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Instead of telling the error message you can show the exact one.

Answer (score 0):

You should seperate the queries by semicolon

```
string cmdText = @"INSERT INTO [Sales] 
                ([Printers], [Ink], [Paper])
       VALUES (@Printers,@Ink,@Paper);
       SELECT @EmpID FROM (Emplopyee)";
```

Also you can't pass the column name as parameter. In that case use dynamic query.

Comment: error: Characters found after end of SQL statement.

Comment: Read last line of my answer.

Comment: sorry but i'm not sure what a dynamic query is

Comment: What is the meaning of `SELECT @EmpID FROM (Emplopyee)`? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to make it so it inserts the Sales data  of certain salesman depending on their Employee id

Comment: If you know the `EmpID` just insert it in your `INSERT` query.

Comment: Its a form the user is filling out so i won't know exactly who's EmpID to insert

Answer (score 0):

you should change the query to this:

```
 string cmdText = @"INSERT INTO [Sales] 
                    ([Printers], [Ink], [Paper], [EmpID])
           VALUES (@Printers,@Ink,@Paper,
                   SELECT EmpID FROM (Employee) )";
```

Comment: When i use this query i get the error:  You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table 'Employees'.

Comment: I get the error: Syntax error in query expression 'SELECT @EmpID FROM (Emplopyee)'.

Comment: I fixed my answer, if you need to insert four columns including empID

Comment: now it says: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Answer (score 0):

It most likely should read:

```
string cmdText = @"INSERT INTO [Sales] 
    ([Printers], [Ink], [Paper], [EmpID])
    VALUES (@Printers, @Ink, @Paper, @EmpID)";
```

Comment: That gives me the error: The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship. Change the data in the field or fields that contain

Comment: Its a form where the user enters their id and their sales. It inserts the sales for that employee based on their employee id

Comment: Check the table design of Sales, EmpID should not be a primary key or disallows duplicates as multiple employees can make many sales. The autonumber in Sales should be PK.

Comment: @Parfait is right. Your syntax is now OK but your data (or table structure) are not.

Answer (score 0):

The "cmd.Paramter.AddWithValue" are unnecessary.

Try formatting your cmdText as

```
 cmd = "INSERT INTO [Sales] ([Printers], [Ink], [Paper])
     VALUES (" + txtPrinters.Text + " ," + txtInk.Text + ", " + txtPaper.Text + ")
```

This clears up confusion of "cmd.Paramter.AddWithValue" duplicating or overriding values.

Rewritten btnUpdate_Click (also not sure if Emplopyee is a typo or not)

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\cp-stud-nas1\users\mat72462\Documents\SalesData.accdb"))
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, con))
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd = "INSERT INTO [Sales] ([Printers], [Ink], [Paper]) VALUES (" + txtPrinters.Text + " ," + txtInk.Text + ", " + txtPaper.Text + ") SELECT " + textEmpID.Text + " FROM (Emplopyee)";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [Total Sales] FROM Sales WHERE EmpID=@EmpID";
        string result = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(result);

    }
}
```

Comment: So should i get rid of the cmd.Paramter.AddWithValue lines if so then where should i place the string cmdtext line at?

Comment: The cmdText line should be written out at the point that the text fields are they values you want.
e.g.
Button Clicked
Initialize cmdText
Execute query